# Xamarin - Video Cropping for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I was wondering if there was a way to crop videos in Xamarin. I can't seem to find any examples. I tried looking at the existing functions and Classes but I couldn't find anything.

Basically make square videos like what Vine and Instagram have. I think this is done by cropping out the rest of the video and not just zooming in.

Comment: You might want to make it clearer what you're trying to accomplish. I'm guessing you don't want to actually edit the video, just "zoom in" on a part of the video for displaying to the user? Perhaps to eliminate black borders?

Comment: @mason Basically I want to get what Vine has where you get square videos. So I'm not sure how Vine does it by zooming in or by actually cropping out the rest of the video. So my video would go from something like 1920x1080 to 800x800 just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I find part of the code from one source, I tried to add owner but I could  not find. The solution's key part is added by me for cropping which is "VideoCleanAperture" inside AVVideoSettingsCompressed.

```
                videoUrl = ((AVFoundation.AVUrlAsset)avAsset).Url;
                NSError assetReaderError;
                var assetReader = AVAssetReader.FromAsset(avAsset, out assetReaderError);
                var assetTrack = avAsset.Tracks.First();

                //Height = (System.nint?)avAsset.NaturalSize.Height,
                    //Width = (System.nint?)avAsset.NaturalSize.Width,
               var inputSettings = new AVVideoSettingsUncompressed()
               {
                    Height = (System.nint?)avAsset.NaturalSize.Height,
                    Width = (System.nint?)avAsset.NaturalSize.Width,
               };
               var assetReaderOutput = new AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(assetTrack, settings: inputSettings);
               assetReaderOutput.AlwaysCopiesSampleData = false;

               string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "CroppedVideo.mp4");
               if (File.Exists(tempFile)) File.Delete(tempFile);
               var url = NSUrl.FromFilename(tempFile);
               NSError assetWriterError;
               var assetWriter = new AVAssetWriter(url, AVFileType.Mpeg4, out assetWriterError);



               var outputSettings = new  AVVideoSettingsCompressed()
               {
                   Height = 300,
                   Width = 300,
                    Codec = AVVideoCodec.H264,
                   CodecSettings = new AVVideoCodecSettings()
                   {
                       AverageBitRate = 1000000, 
                        VideoCleanAperture = new AVVideoCleanApertureSettings(
                            new NSDictionary(
                            AVVideo.CleanApertureWidthKey, new NSNumber(300),
                            AVVideo.CleanApertureHeightKey, new NSNumber(300),
                            AVVideo.CleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey, new NSNumber(10),
                            AVVideo.CleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey, new NSNumber(10)
                            )
                        )    
                   }, 

                    ScalingMode = AVVideoScalingMode.ResizeAspectFill
               };


                var assetWriterInput = new AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.Video, outputSettings: outputSettings);
                assetWriterInput.ExpectsMediaDataInRealTime = false;
               assetWriter.AddInput(assetWriterInput);

               assetWriter.StartWriting();
               assetReader.AddOutput(assetReaderOutput);
               assetReader.StartReading();
               assetWriter.StartSessionAtSourceTime(CoreMedia.CMTime.Zero);

               var mediaInputQueue = new DispatchQueue("mediaInputQueue");
               assetWriterInput.RequestMediaData(mediaInputQueue, () =>
               {
                   while (assetWriterInput.ReadyForMoreMediaData)
                   {
                       var nextBuffer = assetReaderOutput.CopyNextSampleBuffer();
                       if (nextBuffer != null)
                       {
                           assetWriterInput.AppendSampleBuffer(nextBuffer);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           assetWriterInput.MarkAsFinished();
                           assetWriter.FinishWritingAsync();
                           assetReader.CancelReading();
                           assetReader.Dispose();
                           assetReaderOutput.Dispose();
                           assetWriter.Dispose();
                           assetWriterInput.Dispose();
                           break;
                       }
                   }
               });
            }
```